# can anyone tell me why body{ overflow: auto;} does not work? I have tried adding a class to the body tag and then again... It does not work.. I tried

Tags: html, css

I need to know why adding body tags to my code in Visual Studio code does not work.. It is unlikely to be a syntax error in CSS.

```
  body{
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, 
    Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300; 
    overflow: auto;
               }
```

Comment: With CSS I've found most problems come from an overriding element. Check the other elements (I like to use Inspect Element) for any overriding effects. Could it also be that CSS is doing its job and you're actually looking for a different attribute or value?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `width` for the horizontal scroll to work
and `height` for the vertical